When is projection faster than linear minimization?
Let $C$ be a nonempty compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The projection operator of $C$ is
$$\textrm{proj}_C\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n\colon x\mapsto \underset{c\in C}{\textrm{Argmin}}\|x-c\|^2,$$
and a linear minimization oracle of $C$ is any selection of the mapping
$$\textrm{LMO}_C\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n\colon x\mapsto\textrm{LMO}_C(x)\in \underset{c\in C}{\textrm{Argmin}}\,c^\top x.$$
It's known that, for a variety of sets, "evaluating $\textrm{proj}_C$ may be slower than evaluating $\textrm{LMO}_C$". In fact, even if they have the same order of complexity (e.g., when $C$ is the $\ell_1$ ball or the unit simplex), the pre-factor still appears to be better for $\textrm{LMO}_C$ over $\textrm{proj}_C$. One such reference is
here.
Question: Does this phenomenon (computational complexity of $\textrm{proj}_C$ being $\leq$ computational complexity of $\textrm{LMO}_C$) always happen? Of course, we can achieve equality for $C$ being a singleton; however, I'm curious if there are cases where the projection is strictly faster. Possible solutions include:

A set $C$ such that $\textrm{proj}_C$ is provably faster than the currently best-known method of evaluating $\textrm{LMO}_C$. (I would also accept a set $C$ such that we can evaluate $\textrm{proj}_C$ in closed form or finite-computation while $\textrm{LMO}_C$ is not tractable.)
A reference and/or proof that $\textrm{proj}_C$ must be at least as slow as $\textrm{LMO}_C$


The computational complexity depends on how $C$ is given.  For example, $C$ might be a polyhedron given by its vertices, or it might be given by a linear system of inequalities, or it might be $\left{ x  | | x |_{1}\leq 1 \right}$.

@BrianBorchers yes exactly, e.g., for certain polyhedra we can project onto them very efficiently (although AFAIK still not faster than LMO).

Here is a weak argument why LMO is "easier": $LMO(x)$ can be obtained by $\lim_{t\to\infty} proj(t x)$. Often (always?) this can be used to turn a fast algorithm for $proj$ into a fast algorithm for $LMO$.

@gerw I agree with the intuition, and it feels like this should be true. I'd be interested to see a work in this direction with a more explicit error bound (e.g., for $t$ larger than $f(\varepsilon)$, then $|\textrm{proj}(tx)-\textrm{LMO}(x)|\leq \varepsilon$). I'd also be concerned about numerical roundoff issues if we take $t$ to be large enough to guarantee $\varepsilon$ is less than machine epsilon.

correction: we must flip the sign: I think we mean $\textrm{LMO}(x)$ is approached by $\lim_{t\to \infty} \textrm{proj}(-tx)$. Here's a graph
